# An intrinsic characterization of perfect complexes on smooth proper varieties

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Suppose $X$ is a smooth proper variety over a field. Then for $F$ perfect complex on $X$, $RHom_X(F,F)$ is perfect over the ground field. Is it true that if $RHom(F,F)$ is perfect over $k$, then $F$ is perfect (assuming that $F$ is quasicoherent)?

Comment: You need more to get smoothness and properness altogether: properness alone is sufficient to get that RHom(F,G) is perfect for any bounded complexes of coherent sheaves F and G.

Comment: Sorry i didn't realize that my question was badly worded, i assume smooth proper always and I'm asking if that condition implies perfect. I'll edit

Comment: @D.-C.Cisinski I don't think's actually true. Consider $F=G=k$ as a module over $k[\epsilon]/(\epsilon^2)$ (say $k$ a field). If $F$ is perfect then what you say is true. Still it seems likely the answer to the question is "no" but I don't know a specific example.

Comment: @onefishtwofish Combine https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/073G and https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/02O5

Comment: Sorry what do you mean by $\text{RHom}(F,F)$ is finite? Do you mean it lives in $D^b(k)$? Or do you mean each of its cohomology sheaves is finite dimensional over $k$? Also for your question, what are you assuming about $F$ to start with? It lives in $D^b_{\text{qc}}(X)$?

Comment: I would like the RHom to be finite dimensional and bounded. for the second question F should also be coherent (perfect and coherent (in the derived sense) are the same here)

Comment: @davik the question is what do you already assume about $F$? Is it just in $D(\mathcal O_X)$, or at least quasi-coherent? Is it already assumed bounded?

Comment: Ah i see, sorry yes i assume F is quasicoherent

Comment: @onefishtwofish you are right: we need F perfect and G bounded coherent to get RHom(F,G) perfect in the case where X is proper.

Comment: @davik I do not know the answer to your question, but something related: assuming X is smooth and proper, if E is a complex of quasi-coherent sheaves such that RHom(F,E) is perfect for any perfect F, then E is perfect. This can be found in Toen's paper on dg categories (arXiv:math/0408337) Lemma 8.16.

Answer (score 1):

(Thanks to Bhargav for this example, any mistakes are of course my own)

The converse is false. Let $E$ be an elliptic curve and $L$ be a degree zero line bundle such that $L^{\otimes n}$ is not trivial for any $n$. Then, if $Y$ is the total space of $L$, then $Y$ has finite quasicoherent cohomology groups even though it is not proper. This is because degree zero line bundles on elliptic curve have no quasicoherent cohomologies unless it is trivial.

Now embed $Y$ inside a smooth projective surface $X$ and consider $F := j_*\mathcal{O}_Y$. Then $RHom(F,F)$ on $X$ simply calculate the quasicoherent cohomology of $Y$, which we established is  finite.